# Find and delete columns that are empty in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataset which is a random sample from a database. Some columns are so sparse that they are empty in the sample. How can I programatically have R find columns that are empty and then drop them from the dataset?

Comment: What is in these columns, all `NA`s?

Comment: Try this `dataset [,colSums(is.na(dataset )) <nrow(dataset),drop=FALSE]` to get rid of empty columns.

Answer (score 3):

Using this sample table

```
dd<-data.frame(
    a=1:5,
    b=1:5,
    c=rep(NA,5),
    d=1:5,
    e=rep(NA,5)
)
```

The following code will look over all the columns of dd to see if all the values are `NA`. If they are, then it will not include them in the final data set.

```
dd <- dd[, !sapply(dd, function(x)all(is.na(x))), drop=F]
```